# How can I make automatic a process?

Tags: android, gps

I make a tutorial of GPS that you can get the location pressing a button, but now I want to make this process automatically, I try calling it on the onCreate method but only works once.... any Idea how? this is what i try:

GPS CLASS

```
public class GPS implements LocationListener{

private final Context mContext;

//flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnable = false;

// Flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnable = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location;  //location
double latitude;     //latitude
double longitude;   //longitude

// the minimum distances to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // Minimun distance 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in millisenconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BTW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 MINUTE

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPS(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //getting GPS status
    isGPSEnable = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        //getting network status
        isNetworkEnable = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(!isGPSEnable && !isNetworkEnable){
            // no network provider is enable
        }
        else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if(isNetworkEnable){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BTW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, (LocationListener) this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if(locationManager != null){
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if(location != null){
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enable get lat/long using GPS Services
            if(isGPSEnable){
                if(location == null){
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BTW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS ENABLE", "GPS Enabled");
                    if(locationManager != null){
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null){
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 */

public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if (locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) GPS.this);
    }
}

/**
 * function to get latitude
 */
public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
    //return latitude
    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
    //return longitude
    return  longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enable
 * @return boolean
 */
public  boolean canGetLocation(){
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will launch Settings Options
 */

public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.AlertDialog_Tittle));

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(mContext.getString(R.string.dialog_message));

    // On pressing Setting button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        }
    });

    // On pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location){

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

and the main-activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private EditText edTLatitud;
private EditText edTLongitud;
private EditText edTCompass;
private EditText edTDirecc;
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor compassSensor;

// GPS class
GPS gps;

// Compass class
Compass compass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gpsactivity);

    edTCompass = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edTxtBrujula);
    edTDirecc = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edTxtBrujdireccion);
    edTLatitud = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edTxtLatitud);
    edTLongitud = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edTxtLongitud);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    compassSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

    gps = new GPS(MainActivity.this);

    // Check if GPS is enable
    if(gps.canGetLocation()){

        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        // Print on the screen the coordinates
        UpdateGPSonScreen(latitude, longitude);
    }
    else {
        // can't get location
        // GPS or network is not enable
        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
}

// Show the Latitude and longitude of the GPS on the application
public  void UpdateGPSonScreen(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    try{
        edTLatitud.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));
        edTLongitud.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

thanks in advance...

Comment: what do you mean by `but now I want to make this process automatically`. Please update the exact requirement. Why your GPS is a service ?

Comment: @pyus13 thanks I will update the code, it not implements service I make a mistake on that part... what I want to do is to show the location when the conditions are met ...

Comment: How about using a async task.... it could work? or is not a good solution....

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the EditText to be updated with the user location information intermittently? If so, you could create a thread that on intervals calls a function that retrieves the location data.

Comment: Hi @VonL yea, I was thinking on using a timer that x time calls the gps class

Answer (score 0):

If the GPS class is not used anywhere else except in MainActivity make it as inner class of your Activity or Implement LocationListener in your Activity class itself to update your TextViews inside `onLocationChanged` method.

Put `locationManger` null check before you use it anywhere, there is no sense an to check for null after using it multiple times.

Your Class structure should be like

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

   // Define your text views to use them globally

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.gpsactivity);

    //find all your views

   }

   class GPS implements LocationListener{

    //copy all your code here with required correction

      @Override
      public void onLocationChanged(Location location){

       //get your latitude and longitude from location Object
       // call same method to update your view

      }
   }

 }
```

I have written whole code in stackoverflow editor only so make correction if any syntax error is found.

Comment: well, the thing to make it in a separate class is that i want to create a service that calls the gps class to use it for other purposes. or is better to make what you said, and after making the service create another class to call the gps?

Comment: if you want to call the same from somewhere else I think you need to use handlers to update your UI. When do you want to update UI, during location change or call it after period of time using some counter in Service ?

Comment: Well, let me explain what i am tryng to do, is an app that show and store the data of the location and compass through a service and also to give the option to open the app and show the location and compass...